# How to select the median of a list?

Tags: sorting

If I have a list `{3,19.5,85,45/2,5.6}`, how can I select the median of the list without using the built-in `Median` command?

First I sorted the list

```
Sort[{3,19.5,85,45/2,5.6}]
{3, 5.6, 19.5, 45/2, 85}
```

I can't figure out which command to use to select the median without directly using `Median` command.

Comment: Use Part (shortcut [[ ]]) to take the term that is at the position (Length[list]+1)/2

Comment: `Quantile[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, 1/2]`

Comment: Duplicate. See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26650/how-do-i-extract-the-middle-elements-of-a-given-list).

Comment: Ummm... just wondering:  why not use `Median`?

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's a rendering into Mathematica of a very old idiom from the APL programming language (see https://aplwiki.com/wiki/FinnAPL_idiom_library#cite_note-1) that requires no explicit splitting into odd/even cases:

```
    myMedian[lis_] := (1/2) Total[Sort[lis][[Abs@Ceiling[{-1/2, 1/2} (1 + Length@lis)]]]]
```

Tests:

```
    x = RandomInteger[{2, 50}, RandomInteger[{4, 8}]];
    Sort[x]
    {myMedian[x], Median[x]}
(* {4, 9, 31, 34, 39, 40, 40, 44} *)
(* 73/2, 73/2 *)

    x = RandomInteger[{2, 50}, RandomInteger[{4, 8}]];
    Sort[x]
    {myMedian[x], Median[x]}
(* {2, 16, 16, 18, 24, 26, 42} *)
(* 18, 18 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the list is odd, then the median is the middle element of the sorted list.  If the length of the list is even, the median is the average of the two "central" values:

```
myMedian[x_List] := (z = Sort[x];
  len = Length[z];
  If[OddQ[len], z[[(len + 1)/2]], (z[[len/2]] + z[[len/2 + 1]])/2])
```